# select only some of the rows of a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with some info. I know how to select a certain row of the dataframe.

However, I would like to select several of the rows of the dataframe into another dataframe under the following conditions:

1. I don't know how many rows there are
2. I have to select the first and then in an interval.

For example if I have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
                   
print(df)
```

I have

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
1  bar    one  1   2
2  foo    two  2   4
3  bar  three  3   6
4  foo    two  4   8
5  bar    two  5  10
6  foo    one  6  12
7  foo  three  7  14
```

I would like to obtain with an interval of 4

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
4  foo    two  4   8
```

or if the interval is 3

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
3  bar  three  3   6
6  foo    one  6  12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a slice as you would do for an iterable:

```
df.loc[::4]

     A    B  C  D
0  foo  one  0  0
4  foo  two  4  8

df.loc[::3]

     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
3  bar  three  3   6
6  foo    one  6  12
```

*NB. You can also use `df[::4]`/`df[::3]`, but `loc` is more versatile (for example for columns: `df.loc[:,::3]`).*

Comment: I also found you can do `df[1::3]` if I want to start from the second one